# is ruby rm_rf asynchronous?

Tags: ruby, io

if I do

```
rm_rf('somewhere')
mkdir('somewhere')
```

every so often, the `mkdir` throws a `Permission Denined`. Is this because the `rm_rf` runs asynchronously and sometimes hasnt finished deleting the dir before the `mkdir` runs?

How do I make it block until its completed the delete?

running this on Windows btw.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a feature of NTFS, see [Microsoft Suppport](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=159199):

> This file is in a state known as pending deletion. This file has been
>   deleted, but there are still handles open to it. NTFS will wait until
>   all handles to this file are closed before updating the index. If an
>   attempt is made to access the file, however, NTFS will deny the
>   attempt. Because the file is listed in the index, but is effectively
>   deleted, you can see the file but you cannot access it.

And looking at the solutions, I don't think there is much to do other than to wait and retry.

Answer (score 3):

`rm_rf` is **synchronous**, as any other usual ruby method.

and if it was'nt then you'd probably get a `Errno::EEXIST` error, but you are getting 'permission denied'.

as a workaround try to insert small delay, like `sleep(0.1)` between `rm_rf` & `mkdir`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error too and renamed it first as a workaround:

```rb
  build_dir.directory? &&
    build_dir.rename(old_build_dir) &&
    FileUtils.rm_rf(old_build_dir)
  build_dir.mkdir
```

(`build_dir` and `old_build_dir` are `Pathname` objects)

Not perfect but better than a random `sleep`.